# Trouble building regex to compile with regcomp

Tags: c, regex

I am trying to build a regular expression to satisfy strings like the following: `${AnyTextHere}`. This is what I have right now: `\\${[a-zA-Z0-9]+}` It works in some online regular expression checkers, but not with regcomp.

Comment: https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/using-regular-expressions-2/ try this article you have to do some changes to your regular expression ..

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  As it is, we don't even know which regular-expression library you're using.  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You may also have to escape curly braces `{`, as they are considered *regex special characters*.

```
\\$\\{[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\}
    ^              ^
```

see **[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TdZfzD/1)**

Comment: For some reason that matches everything now. I had to modify it to do get rid of all errors. It is this now: `\\$\\{[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\}`

Comment: how would I make it work? I've never done a regular expression in c.

Comment: Oh I got it working. Your answer is correct.